# how to remove in javascript from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array headings where I push elements:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
  headings.push({
    text: i,
    type: "♠",
  });
}
```

Now I want to remove for example the element `[3,♠]`
I tried with `pop()` or something like that, but I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: Try splice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> ["javascript array remove element"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+remove+element)

Answer (score 2):

```
const idx = headings.findIndex(el => el.text === 3 && el.type === "♠")
headings.splice(idx,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it.

You can use `filter` or `splice` method to do it.

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
Here you can filter all other element then 3 and "♠" and assign it to new array.

[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
Here find index of your element and use `splice` on array

```js
let headings = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
  headings.push({
    text: i,
    type: "♠",
  });
};

let newHeadingsFilter = headings.filter(x => !(x.text === 3 && x.type == "♠"));
console.log(newHeadingsFilter);

let index = headings.findIndex(x => x.text == 3 && x.type == "♠");
headings.splice(index, 1);

console.log(headings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter

```
const newHeadings = headings.filter(item => !item.type === "♠")
```

If you also want to check for the value of `i`

```
const newHeadings = headings.filter((item, index)=> !(item.type === "♠" && item.text == (index + 1)))
```

This returns a new array and does not modify original

Answer (score 0):

Use `lodash`'s [`_.remove`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#remove):

```js
const headings = _.range(1, 13).map(i => ({text: i, type: "♠"}));
_.remove(headings, {text: 3, type: "♠"});
console.log(headings);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This removes all matching elements, not just the first one.

Comment: _"Use lodash..."_ to remove an element from an array? Seriously? o.O

Comment: @Andreas it's still a useful library. Use it if it saves time for your project. Don't use it if this is your only use for it.

Comment: There's no tag and OP didn't mention lodash in the question. So why recommend a specific library? Should every reader now add his personal favorite?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not recommending the library, just providing an answer to the question that will be helpful for some users. Yes, readers should add answers that use libraries, whether or not their personal favorite.